# How to control paging in Fluent UI React Details List

Tags: typescript, fluent-ui

I have some items I'm outputting via the DetailsList component. However it seems to be creating a paging wrapper div after 10 items, which is breaking my layout. I can't find any kind of property to control this... am I missing something?
My component:

```
 <DetailsList
          setKey="items"
          items={this.state.items}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          selection={this._selection}
          selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
          onRenderItemColumn={this.onRenderCell}
          dragDropEvents={this._dragDropEvents}
          checkboxVisibility={CheckboxVisibility.hidden}
          isHeaderVisible={false}
          className={styles.detailsList}
                    onRenderRow={this._onRenderRow}
                        
        />
```

and in my output, every 10 items it's inserting a wrapper div

```
<div class="ms-List-page">
```

how can I prevent this "ms-List-page" wrapper from being inserted?

Comment: Why is it breaking your layout? From a quick look (I've not looked at this library before so good chance I'm wrong) it looks to me like it's probably related to the virtualization of rows so that they don't all need to be rendered at once. There is an attribute called onShouldVirtualize that allows you to turn this off but the ms-List-page divs remain in place (though they all get rendered at once and don't have heights set on them as far as I can see). I think you might be able to use onShouldVirtualize like `onShouldVirtualize={(props: IListProps) => false}` but I don't really know TS.

Comment: thanks... yeah I tried that property and it still generates the pages at every 10 items...

Comment: Looks I can in theory pass List component props to DetailsList using listProps... I think then I can use getPageSpecification but it's not recognizing that property